# MVC and singleton JS objects?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

I'm at the very beginning stages of an MVC project.

**View:**

```
<h4>About Me</h4>
<!-- ko if: !isEditingAboutMe() -->
<p data-bind="text: aboutMe()">@Model.AboutMe</p>
@if (Model.CurrentUserCanEdit)
{
    <a data-bind="click: editAboutMe">edit</a>
}
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: isEditingAboutMe() -->
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AboutMe, new { data_bind = "value: aboutMe" })
<a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe">save</a>
<a data-bind="click: cancelAboutMe">cancel</a>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new ProfileVm(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))));</script>
```

**ProfileVm:**

```
function ProfileVm(model) {
var self = this;

self.aboutMe = ko.observable(model.AboutMe);

self.saveAboutMe = function() {
    // need to put call to dataservice here
    self.isEditingAboutMe(false);

};

self.cancelAboutMe = function() {
    self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
};

self.isEditingAboutMe = ko.observable(false);
self.editAboutMe = function() {
    self.isEditingAboutMe(true);
};
}
```

Now, I just made a **dataservice.js** file:

```
// should I init an object?  Not sure how to use this service across multiple js viewmodels
var dataservice = {
updateAboutMe: updateAboutMe  // some AJAX function
}
```

My question - I need to use this dataservice across multiple JS viewmodels.  How can I do this in a way that doesn't require newing up a new dataservice object for every model?  I just need a singleton but I don't know A) how to structure the contents of dataservice.js to facilitate this, or B) how to init/require the dataservice singleton from callers, like profileVm.

I'm not sure if this is where requireJS would come into play, or if I can do it with straight js.  Any tips would be awesome.